# Flexbox does not give equal width to all elements even when flex-shrink and flex-grow set to 0

Tags: html, css, flexbox, web-frontend

I have a div container inside an article.

```
<article>
        <div class="flex">
            <article class="img"><img src="Demo.webp" alt="Demo" height="250px" /></article>
            <div style="background-color: red;"></div>
            <section style="background-color: blue;"></section>
        </div>
        <button class="add-to-cart">Add To Cart</button>
</article>
```

This is the CSS to my `flex` container:

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
    flex: 0 0 0;
}
```

According to my understanding, if I set flex-shrink and flex-grow to 0 (which I have done using the flex property) then each of the child elements of this flexbox should have equal width. When inspecting the web page however, they have a width of 0 (therefore it cannot be seen).

The browser gives the following error:

**The display: block property on the parent element prevents flex from having an effect.
Try setting the display: block property on the parent to display: flex.**

Please help me by explaining the error and the solution.

Similar questions have been asked on Stack Overflow in the past, but I could not find any with my exact same situation. In my case the flex property (flex-basis, flex-grow, flex-shrink) are **not** working as described in other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink#formal_definition) and/or [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow#formal_definition) properties are not inherited by children. They should not be applied to the parent but to the element itself.

This should be working :

```css
 .flex {
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
}

.flex > * {
    display: flex;
    flex : 1;
}
```

`.flex > *` targets all direct children of your `.flex` elements.

`flex: 1` will make all your elements have the same width see :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Hope that helps !